# How to display Subreport records in the first page of the Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2008, subreports

I have created one Crystal Report with two Subreports.
Here I included both the Subreports in the Detail Section.
My first Subreport shows only one row. So it displays below the Header Section in the First Page. But the second subreport has 25 rows. So it displays in the second page not under the first subreport.
If the second subreport has very few records(example. 5 rows) then the subreport is displaying in the first page.
How to display the second subreport's records under the first subreport?
Another issue is, My Header Section records are displaying in all the pages. From the second page onwards, I want to display only the subreport records. How to remove the Header section from the second page onwards?
Is there any formula to do this?
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having with your header section showing up on all pages is because you have this data in your page header, but you want to put that info on the report header.

The default display of reports is:

Report Header (first page only)

Page Header (all pages)

Details

Report Footer (first page only)

Page Footer (all pages)

Clean up this issue first and then I believe your initial issue may resolve itself.

Answer (score 1):

put your subreports in header sections instead of detail section in your main report.

main report

header

subreport1

subreport2

detail
//closed

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your two issues:

1. It sounds like your second subreport is sometimes too long to fit on the page. If you want it on the first page, you'll have to make it shorter, or else free up some vertical space from something else that displays on the first page.
2. If possible, move your content from the **Page Header** to the **Report Header**. If that doesn't work, for some reason, set a **Suppress** formula on the page header:

   ```
   PageNumber > 1
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To stop the subreport jumping to the next page you need to right click on the subreport and open the "format subreport" box....then deselect the "keep object together" option.